# Using CPack, when building on OSX, how to avoid ending up with the suffix Darwin in the package/bundle filename?

Tags: macos, cmake, cpack

When I build using CPack on OSX, my resulting package name has "Darwin" in the filename.  I don't want it there as it serves no purpose these days.  How do I tell CPack not to add that?

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make && ctest && cpack -G "Bundle
```

And I get:

```
myapp-1.2.3-Darwin.dmg
```

I want instead:

```
myapp-1.2.3.dmg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file name is controlled by the `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` variable, which you need to set before you call `include(CPack)`. The default value for this is:

```
${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-${CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME}
```

In your case, you want something like this (assuming you've already set `CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME` and `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION`):

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
```

These variables and more are discussed in the CMake docs for the [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html) module.

Comment: The key was to do this before `INCLUDE(CPACK)` and also, I have to set CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION before it as well otherwise, the CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION is blank before including CPACK